# Swapped names of two partitions C and D drives - won't boot up

Tags: windows-7, windows

As far as I know they somehow swapped and now I can't access PC. It won't boot, even in safe-mode. It goes through windows logo and then gives blue-screen.

What can I do to restore everything back to normal?

Also, note that it is one HDD, two partitions. One has windows installed on it.

Comment: Do you mean the name of the drive?

Comment: @chmod How do I do that? Note that I can't go to safe-mode.

Comment: @chmod Yes, exactly.

Comment: How/What did you do to swap it in the first place?

Comment: The name of the drive shouldn't really matter, only the drive letter that is. I can rename my C drive to whatever and my D drive to whatever and it will still boot

Comment: @chmod I forgot to add that those two were partitions from one HDD, still if I change names everything should run fine?

Comment: No it won't run fine. Everything that is hard-coded will fail.

Comment: @RandolphWest: I've yet to see something hardcoded to the drive *name*.

Comment: I've been in software development for many years, and seen some very scary things. It's in a small realm of possibility, but it exists. Software that will make assumptions from the drive name.

Comment: Your assumptions about the cause of your issue are possibly incorrect. Please take a step back. What is the BSOD that you're seeing? Does it show a STOP code? If so, which one? What was the last thing you did before the issue started appearing?

Answer (score 2):

First off, your description of your problem is extremely vague.  Please clarify it.  However, from what I think you are saying, your assumption is wrong.  If for some reason the boot process is trying to boot from the wrong partition, you should be getting an error along the lines of "Invalid boot partition."  If you are getting a blue screen error, then the machine is booting properly, but something else is wrong, like a bad driver, corrupt sectors on the hard drive, etc...

Answer (score -1):

Once you find the correct partition, reset the boot order, sounds like the bios defaulted somehow on the boot order, just needs to be set right.

Regards,

Comment: And this works with two partitions on the same physical drive too?